# convert bootstrap click to hammer tap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, hammer.js

How to convert bootstrap click handler, with hammer.js `tap` event?

Because touch devices have a delay before executing click event, and that's boring for users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use FastClick to process 300ms delay:

https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick

If FastClick used, you can just use `click`, it will be processed automatically.